# How to obtain actual server port when started with 0 in a SpringBoot 3 application started with SpringApplication.run()?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Assume a Spring Boot 3 application started programmatically with:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, new String[]{"--server.port=0", ...
```

once the server is started, it will bind on an available port.
I need to get such value.

In Spring Boot 2, I could get it with:

```
return (Integer) ((Map) ctx.getEnvironment()
   .getPropertySources().get("server.ports").getSource())
   .get("local.server.port");
```

But this unfortunately does not seem to work anymore (at least on a SB 3.1.3 application I tried it on).

How can the same be achieved in Spring Boot 3?

UPDATE:
I should have specified that the application cannot be modified. So injecting values does not work. Either the info should be retrieved from `ConfigurableApplicationContext`, or the application should be started in a different way.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-running-port#getting-random-port-at-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help.
In the end, it was an issue on the default configurations of that application. It was mistakenly started without the web server, and the logs for Spring classes were disabled (so could not see the problem).

The approach that worked from SpringBoot 2 still seems working for 3.
Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

`@Value("${local.server.port}")` returns the server port allocated at the runtime.

Answer (score 2):

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-running-port#1-using-servletwebserverapplicationcontext)

You can use `ServletWebServerApplicationContext`:

```
@Autowired
private ServletWebServerApplicationContext webServerAppCtxt;
...
int port = webServerAppCtxt.getWebServer().getPort();
```

You can also handle `ServletWebServerInitializedEvent` using service:

```
@Service
public class ServerPortService {
    private int port;

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ServletWebServerInitializedEvent event) {
        port = event.getWebServer().getPort();
    }
}
```

Then just inject service as any other:

```
@Autowired
private ServerPortService serverPortService;
...
int port = serverPortService.getPort();
```